# Android Studio 4.0 Update, cannot delete builder-model-0.6.1.jar

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

So when updating android studio (on windows 7) from 3.7.0 to 4.0.0 I get the error:
[image]

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Launch Android Studio (or the updater) in admin mode.

If no success, remove it yourself !

Answer (score 0):

This is bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63927. The workaround is to just try it again.